# Find specific words in text file and using java

Tags: java, search, words

Need some help in solving the problem. There is a text document in which i want to find words qwee, deff and add the result (qwee = 12130, deff = 110). The result is save to the another txt file. Which way should I use?

--------- 2016-08-08 12:32:52 GMT+03:00 S03 ---------
Mii::QW,;
LOADING PROGRAM 
MM      S03                  2016-08-08  12:32:50
NAME          INDEX     COUNT
qwee                  1  :  12130
Ssss                  2  :     10
deff                  3  :    110

### fede                  4  :     10

Total: 2333903
COMMAND EXECUTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this example and see if it solves your problem. I assume you keep this file

**data.txt**

```
--------- 2016-08-08 12:32:52 GMT+03:00 S03 --------- Mii::QW,; LOADING PROGRAM MM S03 2016-08-08 12:32:50 NAME INDEX COUNT qwee 1 : 12130 Ssss 2 : 10 deff 3 : 110

fede 4 : 10

Total: 2333903 COMMAND EXECUTED
```

Then we run the program

```
import java.io.*;;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String content = new Scanner(new File("data.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            String split[] = content.split("( )|(\n)");
            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    if (split[i].equals("qwee")) {
                        writer.write("qwee " + split[i + 3] + "\n");
                    }
                    if (split[i].equals("deff")) {
                        writer.write("deff  " + split[i + 3] + "\n");
                    }                    ;
                }
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                ;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It created a new file with the data you want

**output.txt**

```
qwee 12130
deff  110
```